# Method Expression is not of function type (equals on a state property/value) - React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently trying to do conditional statements which allow me to display the divs according to the User's role. First I call for the role and set it to the state value.

The sets are fine as I can view in the dev tools console. However when I try to do the following conditional check on a constant which is a string:

```
props = {
     subRole = ''
}


{(!this.state.AdminRole && subRole.toString() === READ_ONLY (
       //div goes here
))}
```

Then I get:

```
  Object(...) is not a function
```

on the `subRole.toString() === READ_ONLY` check and Webstorm is telling:

```
  method expression is not of function type
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared subRole incorrectly. In object notation we use `:` for keys.

Please do the following changes first:

```
props = {
     subRole : ''
}
```

If you want to initialize default props:

```
// for example your component is App.js

App.defaultProps = {
  roles : {
    subRole: 'c'
  }
};
```

Later you can access this in your component like:

```
this.props.roles.subRole
```

This is the recommended way but usually we don't use default props, instead we are more concerned with the component's default state.

Answer (score 0):

READ_ONLY is being called as a method which is why you get the error. Add `&&` before rendering element:

```
{(!this.state.AdminRole && subRole.toString() === READ_ONLY && (
       //div goes here
))}
```

Also, Fix `=`

```
props = {
     subRole : ''
}
```